# Q: Bash script infinite loop causing ffmpeg spam

Tags: linux, bash, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

Can't seem to figure this one out... I have a set up NGINX server with the excellent RTMP extension and everything is working fine. However, I'm trying to restream/push a copy of a couple specific streams that need to be streamed in another RTMP stream application (specifically, these streams are streamed to application "static" but in the current situation also need to be pushed over to "live"). The process of restreaming/pushing a stream in NGINX-RTMP is relatively simple, however, in my case I need to selectively push a couple of streams instead of every stream being streamed to the application "static".

Idea is to have NGINX-RTMP pass the stream name off to the bash script, which then does the restreaming without interrupting any other streams or services.

With some success, I've tried doing this by creating a bash scrip..

The relevant NGINX config bit that runs the bash script is:

```
exec_publish /etc/nginx/rtmp_conf.d/stream_id.sh $name;
```

I tried it with an "if / else"

```
if [ $1 == "stream_name_1" ]; then
        ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_0
elif [ $1 == "stream_name_2" ]; then
        ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_2 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_1
elif [ $1 == "stream_name_3" ]; then
        ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_3 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_2
elif [ $1 == "stream_name_4" ]; then
        ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_3
else
        echo "FAIL" >> /etc/nginx/rtmp_conf.d/stream.log && echo date > /etc/nginx/rtmp_conf.d/stream.log
        exit
fi
```

And I tried it with Switches

```
case "$1" in
        "stream_name_1")
            ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_0
        ;;
        "stream_name_2")
            ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_2 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_1
        ;;
        "stream_name_3")
            ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_3 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_2
        ;;
        "stream_name_4")
            ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_3
        ;;
        echo "FAIL " >> /etc/nginx/rtmp_conf.d/stream.log && echo date > /etc/nginx/rtmp_conf.d/stream.log
esac
```

Problem with both is that they both end up spamming a ton of ffmpeg processes ... and I don't know why - I've tried changing the code but I either end up with ffmpeg not firing at all or spamming the server.

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm trying to do it all at once and that's why I end up with loads of ffmpeg processes - because I'm doing it in a unified way it's causing each "if/else" to be multiplied...  maybe I should do an If/else individually per each of the stream I want to restream?

Comment: Run you script with bash -x to give you be debugging information.

Comment: the `if/else` and `case..esac` versions look to be equivalent. There shouldn't be any reason to be spammed for ffmpegs, unless the calling system `NGINX-RTMP` is running the whole script in the background, which might allow it to start another sub-process tree almost immediately. Is it "checking" for a file, and becuase the file hasn't be hidden that it thinks it should start another process? See if your system has `ptree` and see where the `ffmpeg` processes are being started from (their parent process). Then you have a clue about how this is happening. Good luck.

Comment: If no `ptree`, some versions of `ps` have an option that display its output as a process parent/child tree. Good luck.

Comment: After countless more variations of the bash scripts above, it would seem I stumbled on the problem ... the if/else logic was good and the ffmpeg command also worked, however, it turns out running it with the argument "-vcodec libx264" resulted in it spawning a ton of processes and each using abnormal amount of resources - htop readouts indicated that a single process, each, requested ~600MB memory .... and with 20+ something processes like this, I was basically DOSing myself.

Answer (score 0):

Need more info.
What do ffmpegs say?
Have you checked the $1?
I would like to see the entire script.

Comment: Sorry, but that's the whole script - this is a special one-off situation where this is needed, normally, the live streams would be only sent through the "static" stream application.

Comment: Try to redirect ffmpeg's stderr to a file and post its contents.
Put 2>~/log.txt in the end of a ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my situation ffmpeg didn't like the argument flag "-vcodec  x264" (weird because the source stream is encoded with x264, but oh well), changing it to use "copy" audio and video codec fixed my problem - ffmpeg doesn't spawn tens of processes, each trying to use abnormal resource amounts, anymore.

The examples for the working code in my case is:

To initiate the bash scripts I'm placing this in my NGINX config (which passes the incoming stream name to the bash script as by design of the RTMP module):

```
 exec_publish /etc/nginx/rtmp_conf.d/stream_id.sh $name;
```

Using switches:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    "stream_name_1")
        ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_0
    ;;
    "stream_name_2")
        ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_2 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_1
    ;;
    "stream_name_3")
        ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_3 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_2
    ;;
    "stream_name_4")
        ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/stream_name_4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_3
    ;;
esac
```

And using If/Else:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == "stream_name_1" ]; then
    ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/$1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_0
elif [ $1 == "stream_name_2" ]; then
    ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/$1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_1
elif [ $1 == "stream_name_3" ]; then
    ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/$1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_2
else [ $1 == "stream_name_4" ]; then
    ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/static/$1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:2000/live/live_3
fi
```